# Getting a New ASP.NET Session ID after Expiration in Scrapy

Tags: python, asp.net, cookies, scrapy

I have written a scraper in Scrapy 1.5 that successfully navigates to a webpage (running ASP.NET running on IIS version 8.5), submits a form, and then gets to scraping. After a few hours, all of the pages start returning blank data. I believe that my ASP.NET session id is expiring when this happens. I can never make it through the entire table (several thousand pages) while crawling at a respectful rate, but the table doesn't change from session to session. My approach was to scrape until the pages were returned blank, then go back to the form submission page and resubmit the form. I am keeping track of the page number so that I can pick up where I left off. The problem is that when I resubmit the form, the pages are still returned blank. If I stop the scraper, and set the count variable manually to the last page scraped, it works fine when I restart the scraper. Using fiddler I can see that the only thing that is different is that I have a new ASP.NET session id. So my question is, how can I clear out my ASP.NET session id so that I am given a new one and I can continue scraping? Here is a redacted version of the spider:

```
class assessorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redacted'
    allowed_domains = ['redacted.redacted']
    start_urls = ['http://redacted.redacted/search.aspx']
    base_url = start_urls[0]
    rows_selector = '#T1 > tbody:nth-child(3) > tr'
    numberOfPages = -1
    count = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        #ASP.NET Session Id gets stored in the headers after initial search

        frmdata = {'id':'frmSearch', 'SearchField':'%','cmdGo':'Go'}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url = self.base_url, formdata = frmdata, callback = self.parse_index)
        self.log('Search submitted')

    def parse_index(self, response):
        self.log('proceeding to next page')
        rows = response.css(self.rows_selector)
        if (len(rows) < 50 and self.count != self.numberOfPages):
            self.log('Deficient rows. Resubmitting')
            yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.parse, url = self.base_url, headers='')
        self.log('Ready to yield value')
        for row in rows:
            value = {
               #a whole bunch of css selectors
            }
            yield value
        if self.numberOfPages == -1:
            self.numberOfPages = response.css('a.button::attr(href)')[2].extract().split('=')[-1]
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if self.count <= self.numberOfPages:
                self.log( self.base_url + '?page=' + str(self.count))
                yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.parse_index, url = self.base_url + '?page=' + str(self.count))
```

Note: I have read that making a request with an expired ASP.NET session id should result in a new one being issued (depending on how the site is set up), so it is possible that scrapy is not accepting the new session id. I am not sure how to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that come to mind:

1) Your "start a fresh session" request might be getting rejected by the downloader: [By default, it filters URLs that it's already seen](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request), such as your base url. Try `yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.parse, url = self.base_url, dont_filter=True, headers='')` in your "reset the session request"

2) If that doesn't work (or perhaps in addition to):

I'm pretty new to Scrapy and Python, so there might be a more direct method to "reset your cookies" but specifying a fresh cookiejar should work.

- https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider

The cookiejar is essentially a dict-like object that is tracking your current session's cookies. You can specify the cookiejar key by using `meta`.

```
    # Set up a new session if bad news:
    if (len(rows) < 50 and self.count != self.numberOfPages):
        self.log('Deficient rows. Resubmitting')
        yield scrapy.Request(
            callback=self.parse,
            url=self.base_url,
            dont_filter=True,
            meta={
                # Since you are already tracking a counter,
                # this might make for a reasonable "next cookiejar id" 
                'cookiejar': self.count
            }
        )
```

Now that you are specifying a new cookiejar, you are in a new session. You must take account for this in your other requests, checking whether a cookiejar is set, and continuing to pass this value. Otherwise you end up back in the default cookiejar. It might be easiest to manage this expectation from the very beginning by defining [start_requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests):

```
    def start_requests(self):
        return [
            scrapy.Request(
                url,
                dont_filter=True,
                meta={'cookiejar': self.count}
            ) for url in self.start_urls
        ]
```

Now your other request objects just need to implement the following pattern to "stay in the same session", such as in your parse method:

```
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(
        url = self.base_url,
        formdata = frmdata,
        callback = self.parse_index,
        meta={
            'cookiejar': response.meta.get('cookiejar')
        }
    )
```

Comment: So, I just tried the first way. it seems that when I go back and resubmit the form (regardless of the value of `dont_filter`), that is what breaks the process. After I resubmit the form, the searches no longer work. In fiddler I can see that the `ASP.NET_SessionID` is unchanged before and after the form is resubmitted, even `dont_filter = True`. It seems that resubmitting the form is generating another cookie, but scrapy just keeps on trucking with the old one. I confirmed this behavior in Firefox by clearing cookies then resubmitting the form. I got a new cookie, and it let me view the page.

Comment: I will try the other way in the morning.

Comment: The solution required both `dont_filter = True` on all new requests as well as setting the cookie in a cookiejar. Your answer helped me to understand how scrapy deals with cookies more than the documentation did. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. Check out this part of the docs to disable the dupe_filter overall. If it needs to be on every request, it's easier to just say "Let's not care about dupes today.": https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class